# How to block a website dynamically in C#?

Tags: c#, url, filter, block

I would like to block certain URLs dynamically from Windows Service written in C#. I don't want to do this by writing to hosts file.

For example I would like to block the url `http://example.com` (in all browsers), but also block `http://example.com/another` from 7 to 8 am.

Is this possible, what should I do?

Best regards,
Andrew

Comment: I think writing to hosts is your best bet if you want this to work for all browsers.

Comment: Please use `example.com` for example domain names as specified in [RFC-2606](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2606.html)

Comment: By the way, adding the domain name to the `hosts` file will only block correct name resolution. Processes can still access the site using an IP address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be able to use the [Windows Firewall API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa366453.aspx). See the article, *[Managed classes to view/manipulate the Windows Firewall](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/joncole/archive/2005/12/06/managed-classes-to-view-manipulate-the-windows-firewall.aspx)*, by John Cole.

Comment: Good idea. But if user will turn off firewall it wont work I think. Also it wont work when using third party firewall. I thought that there is some kind of proxy available.

Answer (score -2):

Now, I show the concept for block. google website. I hope this solution will help you.

```
 private void BlockWebsite_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String path = @"C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts";
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(path, true);
        String sitetoblock = "\n 127.0.0.1 google.com";
        sw.Write(sitetoblock);
        sw.Close();
        MessageBox.Show("Site Blocked");
    }
}
```

Comment: The OP requested a solution that does not involve writing to the `/etc/hosts` file. If you insist on doing this, supply a good reason why it must be used in spite of the OP's request.