# how to block application for ever with remote

Tags: vb.net

i know about blocking system but this way not secure

```
        Dim ws As New WebClient
        Dim str As String = ws.DownloadString("http://blocksys.com/Devil.txt")
        If str = "blocking" Then
            MessageBox.Show("This application has been blocked by administrator", "Application blocked", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            Application.Exit()
        End If
    End If
```

this way not secure so

please teach me another way

thank u

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "blocking", "secure", "forever" and "remote".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to block a website dynamically in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5655008/how-to-block-a-website-dynamically-in-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Imports System.Net
Public Class Form1
    Private url As String

    Private Function CheckSite(ByVal url As String) As String
        Dim Block As Boolean = False
        Dim blocklist As String = "blocksys.com,abc.com,domain.com,another.com"
        Dim myList As String() = blocklist.Split(New Char() {","c})
        For Each checkBlock As String In myList
            If url.IndexOf(checkBlock) <> -1 Then Block = True
        Next
        Return Block
    End Function

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        url = TextBox1.Text
        If CheckSite(url) = True Then
            MessageBox.Show("This application has been blocked by administrator", "Application blocked", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            Exit Sub
        Else
            Dim ws As New WebClient
            ws.DownloadString(url)
            'Another process........
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Add Textbox & Button your form and test it.

Comment: What do you want? Block per domain or domain/page ?